# Getting error on remove var data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making hover card on click for every users so i did for one and its working but i want this to work on every user like i have given them unique title and based on that the server will get the data of that particular users but the problem is this is working on only 1 links not for all the links...maybe its because var data is kept store (please correct me if i'm wrong) so i tried to do this on ajax `cache: false` but didn't help then i tried `return false;`,  `return data;` still not use.

So, here is the users links example :

```
<a class="hover" title="user101" href="#">John</a>
<a class="hover" title="user102" href="#">Tonya</a>
```

Ajax :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    $('.hover').click(function () {
        var get_val = $('.hover').attr('title');
        var data = 'vall=' + get_val + '';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'xx.php',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                box.dialog({
                    message: data
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: id of elements must be unique.... use class to group similar elements

Comment: You mean to say Class="hover" ?

Comment: You have a typo on your 'title' attribute: Two `t's` `tittle="user101"`

Comment: @Styli yes hten use class selector `$('.hover').click(function () {`

Comment: after you changed the id atributes to class atributes, change '#hover' to '.hover'

Comment: Tushar Gupta - Edited two `t's`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way.

**HTML**

```
<div class='links'>
  <a title="user101" href="#">John</a>
  <a title="user102" href="#">Tonya</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });
  $('.links').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var get_val = $(this).prop('title');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'xx.php',
        data: {vall: get_val},
        success: function (data) {
            box.dialog({
                message: data
            });
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Working 100% :) you safe'd me bro

Answer (score 0):

> the problem is this is working on only 1 links not for all the links...maybe its because var data is kept store (please correct me if i'm wrong)

you are wrong.. only 1 links is working beacuse you have same id for multiple elements.. each elements should have unique id.

use class instead

```
<a class="hover" title="user101" href="#">John</a>
<a class="hover" title="user102" href="#">Tonya</a>
```

and a class selector and return false after ajax success callback function , at the end

```
$('.hover').click(function () {
    var get_val = $('.hover').attr('title');
     ....
     $.ajax({
      ....
         success:function(){
            ....
          }
     }); 
     return false;
   ..
```

or simply use `preventDefault()` instead of return false

```
 $('.hover').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var get_val = $('.hover').attr('title');
    .....
```

Comment: It's still not working i'm getting the same value from ajax call

Comment: You should use event.preventDefault() instead of return false.